# Symfony - Handle large amount of inserted data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I have been exporting xlsx file and I have a part of code where I insert that data into database.

I have more then 5000 entries and I always time out error. I Don't know what to do. My example is below.

My code:

```
{
        $batchSize = 500;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {

                $user = new User();
                $user->setEmail($userData['email']);
                $user->setUsername($userData['email']);
                $user->setPassword('plainpassword');


            if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {

            $this->em->flush();
            $this->em->clear();

            }
        }

    $this->em->flush();
    $this->em->clear();

   return $userData;

}
```

Comment: SQL timeout or PHP timeout?

Comment: Are you running this in CLI? If not check the [set_time_limit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your php.ini file or the [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time). For CLI by default it's -1.

Comment: It's a PHP timeout error. (504 Gateway Time-out
) @SwaroopDeval

Comment: I will, still I want to boost up duration of inserting.. @Andrei

Comment: Are you reading the whole file into memory at once?

Comment: Yes I do. @Andrei

Comment: If you get a Gateway Timeout than probably your connection will be interrupted, either by PHP's own timeout (see @Andrei) or from your webserver (apache or nginx) or loadbalancer. You might want to move this to a CLI script. You can still trigger export from your API using something like Process.

Comment: If reading the file itself is an issue, you should look into streaming. This might be difficult considering the format you use (something like CSV is usually the easiest to stream). From a quick google search, this library looks promising though: https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Comment: The ORM is not exactly great for batch processing.  You can drop down to the [Doctrine DBAL layer](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html) and just use a prepared statement for inserting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, This operation should be inside a symfony command
Then, you can do like this:

```
     for ($i = 1; $i <= 10000; ++$i) {
          $user = new User();
          $user->setEmail($userData['email']);
          $user->setUsername($userData['email']);
          $user->setPassword('plainpassword');
        }
    // Do the flush only in the end of everything, that will save memory
    $this->em->flush();
```

For example, you have this command as `populate-user`. Then you can call it inside your PHP code with `exec()` function and set the output to `/dev/null`

That will force the code to be execute in background until it will be done

Proof:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you actually tried your posted code? Leaving aside the missing $em->persist() statement, my own experience has been that trying to flush 5000 entities will almost certainly fail.  Nor does flushing outside of the loop "save memory".  Unless of course you have actually tried it and can demo otherwise?  And the suggestion to run it as a command is, well, unusual to say the least.

Comment: There is no limit for query in one transaction. I have added a screenshot of my output in my answer. It only took 2s for 10000 entry